# how to get the average using for loop in python

Tags: python

In this exercise you will create a program that #computes the average of a collection of values #entered by the user. The user will enter 0 as a #sentinel value to indicate that no further values #will be provided. Your program should display an #appropriate error message if the first value entered #by the user is 0.

```
print("You first number should not be equal to 0.")
total=0
average_of_num=0
i=0
num=input("Enter a number:")

for i in num:
    total=total+num
    i=i+1
    num=input("Enter a number(0 to quit):")

if i==0:
   print("A friendly reminder, the first number should not be equal to zero")
else:        
   average_of_num=total/i      
   print("Counter",i)
   print("The total is: ", total)
   print("The average is: ",average_of_num)
```

Comment: So, what is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: What is the point #of all of the #hash symbols?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
entry_list = []
while True:
    user_entry = int(input("Enter a non Zero number(0 to quit entering: "))
    if user_entry == 0:
        break
    entry_list.append(user_entry)

total = 0    
for i in entry_list:
    total = total + i
avg = total/len(entry_list)

print("Counter",len(entry_list))
print("The total is: ", total)
print("The average is: ",avg)
```

Comment: Oww thank you but i only need to use the for loop

Answer (score 0):

If only for loop should be used try this..

```
num=[int(input("Enter a number:"))]
total=0
for i in num:
    if i == 0:
        break
    
    total=total+i
    x = int(input("Enter a number(0 to quit):"))
    if x != 0:
        num.append(x)
    
avg = total/len(num)

print("Counter: ",len(num))
print("The total is: ", total)
print("The average is: ",avg)
```